# how to use common.cs to transfer and store variables

Tags: c#

I have used a common.cs file to store variables from one form. However, the issue i am having is referencing this value in another form. Currently i use:

```
CommonVariables comvar = new CommonVariables


Comvar.Poem = textbox1.text
```

which stores the value and i understand this but i also understand that if i use the code again on another form like this:

```
FormEncryption Encrypt = new FormEncryption

CommonVariables comvar = new CommonVariables
textbox19.text = Encrypt.Poem
```

instead of it referencing the value I stored it actually references a completely unique value. How do I use the value I stored instead of a new value.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Hi, (firstly it would be good to consider the best approach "architecturally" but for now...)

Answer (score 0):

(firstly it would be good to consider the best approach "architecturally" but for now...)
As an immediate answer you would need to define `CommonVariables comvar = new CommonVariables;` as a global possibly static variable, say in the `Program.cs` (or whatever is appropriate in your project).
(BTW your code samples are not quite correct so it would be good in future to copy from your code to ensure no user error creeps in to confuse matters).